# Database content doesn show on production

Tags: django, postgresql, sqlite, django-rest-framework, production

I am struggling to understand what is missing on my application, sorry it seems a little silly question, I am sure is something quite simple that I am not actually looking to.

I have created an API, using REST-FRAMEWORK on my machine and upload it to production, but the content of my database didn't come through.

If you see in the picture the product list appers as empty

[image]

But on my machine it actually has some information

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be redundant to have the same database to both - local and production environment. By default, that is why they have separate database files/services and have to be filled independently.